# Strange compile errors in Linux Eclipse C

Tags: c, linux, eclipse

I'm hoping someone can help me out with this. I'm a Linux & Eclipse noob, but I'm pretty familiar with C/C++, though its been a while since I've used them. When I try to compile I get strange errors. No matter what I do to fix them they don't seem to go away.

You can see the there's a simple `main` function with a little bit of code. There's only 15 lines of code but if you look at the errors they are in external libraries, `stdio.h`.  In `main` it says there's one error at line 11 but that one doesn't make sense.  I assume it's an Eclipse settings problem, but I have no idea what to do to fix it.  Any help would be very appreciated.  By the way I'm using SciLinux and Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2.  Thanks
[image]

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   int *ptr;
   int a;
   a = 20;
   ptr = &a;
   int b;
   b = *ptr;
   printf(" ptr is %d\n",b);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be infinitely preferable if you paste the actual code and the actual error messages in your question, rather than a screenshot (which is hard to read).

Comment: Looks to me like the Compiler cannot find its include files. Check your Eclipse settings and double check how Eclipse calls the compiler.

Comment: @cli_hlt: Pretty sure it *is* finding the include files, because it's complaining about specific lines inside them.

Comment: Also, depending which version of C you're compiling for (And how strict your compiler is being), it may be complaining about the fact that you've declared the variable `b` in the middle of your code instead of at the beginning of the function.  The restriction doesn't exist for C++, and AFAIK had been relaxed for C99.

Comment: It should also be pointed out that according to that screenshot, you haven't saved the file, which could explain the weird mismatch.

Comment: Maybe `ptr` is typedef'd in a header file?  Your C also looks invalid, including declarations after statements (`int b;` after `ptr = &a;`, that's not standard C, although many compilers accept it).

Comment: @KeithRandall: That's standard C99.

Comment: According to screenshot, that is a C program, not a C++ program. Deleting C++ tag.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I added the screen shot because I believe it's an Eclipse issue I'm having.  I'm pretty use to using Visual Studio on Windows.  This is just one example, maybe not the best.  But it seems that I clear the errors and when I recompile they still show up.

Comment: ems that I clear the errors and when I recompile they still show up.  For instance if you look at the error for line 11 it makes no sense.  It says **expected identifier or "(" before "/" token**  even though those tokens aren't anywhere near line 11.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *ptr;
int a;
int b; //<- move to block top declaration 
a = 20;
ptr = &a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the previous compiler have this weird problem relating to C they only accept variables which are declared in the beginning of the function.

So most probably the error is because you have not declared the variable b  at the starting of the block , i suggest you try using a different compiler or be prepared to declare all the variables at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers say, mixing code and declarations is illegal in old fashioned plain C. See:

[Variable declaration placement in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288441/variable-declaration-placement-in-c)

[How to enforce C89-style variable declarations in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099813/how-to-enforce-c89-style-variable-declarations-in-gcc)

In eclipse, the standard version used will depend on the compiler flags passed to the C compiler gcc: either -std=c89 or -std=c99. Depending on how the project is set up, will either be in the Eclipse project properties or a Makefile.